# How To Automate Hadoop Trash Cleanup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I can clear trash under my user folder by running `hadoop fs -expunge`
This gets rid of files that are older than the `fs.trash.interval` value.  Is there a for expunge to happen automatically to recover diskspace?

Also I see the following output when I run expunge

`[cloudera@localhost conf]$ hadoop fs -expunge
14/07/17 15:43:54 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Namenode trash configuration: Deletion interval = 1 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.`

The emptier interval is 0 which suggests that automated clean up is turned off.  Where is this value configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The code](https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-hdfs/blob/b883331/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/NameNode.java#L431-L438) suggests it is called `fs.trash.interval`.

**EDIT:**  Sorry, misunderstood the question.

The emptier implementation itself is [here](https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-common/blob/ca2ff48/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Trash.java#L242-L255), where we can see the relevant constant seems to be `FS_TRASH_CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_KEY`.

Looking [here](https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-common/blob/ca2ff48/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/CommonConfigurationKeysPublic.java#L68-L69) reveals that key to be `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval`.

**EDIT:** Finally found the xml conf entry [here](https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-common/blob/ca2ff489eb805da4700fb15fa49e539f1c195b89/src/java/core-default.xml#L216-L225).

Comment: Thanks phs. I can confirm that the fs.trash.interval is set to 1 minute in test environment. But the trash is not getting cleared automatically. It gets cleared when I run expunge. Do you know what config value controls `Emptier interval = 0` ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I'm not able to locate that log message in the source.  What version of cloudera hadoop are you running?

Comment: I have version 5.0.0-0

Comment: Thanks phs.  The info is correct but it seems that cloudera manager doesn't expose this property for configuration.