# How to *really* reclaim disk space from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

The first step is

```
hdfs dfs -rmr <path>
```

That drops the files to the /.Trash  but does not remove them.

The next step is

```
hdfs dfs -expunge
```

It is unclear what that actually performs - since afterwards we still see:

```
$ hdfs dfs -du -h
279.4 G  .Trash
```

So then .. how to make that `.Trash` go *poof* once and for all ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the `expunge` causes a trash collection to be *scheduled*

```
hdfs dfs -expunge
15/08/30 19:34:32 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Namenode trash configuration: Deletion interval = 360 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
15/08/30 19:34:32 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Created trash checkpoint: /user/stack/.Trash/150830193432
```

Notice that the **checkpoint** for trash was created.  What is a bit worrisome is that the `Emptier interval` is **0**. So then, when will the data actually be removed..

The following are the `core-site.xml` settings (credit to this SOF answer [How To Automate Hadoop Trash Cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814931/how-to-automate-hadoop-trash-cleanup)  for finding them):

https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-common/blob/ca2ff489eb805da4700fb15fa49e539f1c195b89/src/java/core-default.xml#L216-L225

```
<property>
  <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
  <value>0</value>
  <description>Number of minutes after which the checkpoint
  gets deleted.
  If zero, the trash feature is disabled.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.trash.checkpoint.interval</name>
  <value>0</value>
  <description>Number of minutes between trash checkpoints.
  Should be smaller or equal to fs.trash.interval.
  Every time the checkpointer runs it creates a new checkpoint 
  out of current and removes checkpoints created more than 
  fs.trash.interval minutes ago.
  </description>
</property>
```

I am looking into what the practical effect were for those values being set to zero.  That seems to be inconsistent with the `Trash` feature even being enabled..

Answer (score 4):

Try -skiptrash option while deleting. This will delete forever.